# Updating the Case MasterRecordId field in Apex tests

Tags: apex, unit-test, case, fields, merge

I have currently got a bit of code running in my **beforeUpdate** trigger that updates 4 fields of a case once the **MasterRecordId** field is changed. This is because that field is used to distinguish between whether a **Merge** operation has occurred over another update operations.

Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_merge_statements.htm

```
for(Case c : newMap.values()){
        Case oldCase = oldMap.get(c.Id);
        if(c.MasterRecordId != oldCase.MasterRecordId){
            c.Reason_Case_Closed__c = 'Merged';
            c.Level_1__c = 'Merged';
            c.Level_2__c = 'Merged';
            c.Level_3__c = 'Merged';
        }
    }
```

However I am having issues testing this as **MasterRecordId** is treated as a **System Protected** field and thus **not writeable** in the test. It needs to be updated though in order to enter the segment of code I'm trying to test.

**ATTEMPT:** 
I have attempted to change the inserted case by loading up a JSON string of the Case record with the **MasterRecordId** populated as is suggested by this documentation:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332070&type=1&mode=1

```
    @isTest
private static void beforeUpdate_setsValues_on_caseMerge(){
    Case masterCase = TestData.createCase();
    Case caseToMerge = TestData.createCase();
    
    String caseJSON = '{"attributes":{"type":"Case","url":"/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Case/500E0000002nH2fIAE"}, "Id":"500E0000002nH2fIAE","Status":"Closed", "MasterRecordId":"5009E00000EElaoQAD"}';
    caseJSON = caseJSON.replace('500E0000002nH2fIAE', caseToMerge.Id);
    caseJSON = caseJSON.replace('5009E00000EElaoQAD', masterCase.Id);
            
    Test.startTest();
        caseToMerge = (Case) JSON.deserialize(caseJSON, Case.class);
        update caseToMerge;
    Test.stopTest();
    
    system.debug('caseToMerge at the end: ' + caseToMerge);
}
```

Unfortunately in the same way that this bypasses the ability to write system fields it also doesn't register this as changing the **MasterRecordId*. Here's a pic of the debug I put at the bottom of the snippet:
[image]
As you can see from the last line, it has ignored the lines that fill in the **Reason_Case_Closed__c** etc fields.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you explicitly trying to update MasterRecordId? Instead create data and execute operation which will call the merge statement in the original class and MasterRecordId will be updated.

Comment: Hey there! despite developer.salesforce saying "Only leads, contacts, and accounts can be merged." this actually worked out in the end. merge() and database.merge() work fine on Cases. Thanks again! :)

Comment: The documentation was correct at one point. You should file a Documentation Bug to let them know of this oversight.

Comment: Sure I'll go ahead and do that in case someone has this same issue in the future.